# How to solve “at least 2” type of selection question in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling with following type of question:
"A certain salad bar offers a selection of 2 types of lettuce, 4 types of nuts, and 3 proteins. How many different salads can be created consisting of exactly 1 type of lettuce, exactly 4 types of nuts, and at least 2 proteins?"

Can someone help me with this one? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the question if it is exactly 2? If so, a possible way to approach  this would be to summing the possibilities in the case for 2 proteins and 3 proteins.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Seems very obvious now. So basically, 2 x 1 x (3+1).

Comment: Can such problem be approached with courting principle? I used combination formula for above calculation. Like slotting, LNNNNPP and putting possibilities.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by counting principle?  As you said, you can use combinatorial formulae, there are $\binom{2}{1}$ ways of choosing 1 type of lettuce, $\binom{4}{4}$ ways of choosing 4 types of nuts, and $\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{3}$ ways of choosing at least 2 proteins. That feels like counting to me!

Comment: The two counting principles you used in your answer are the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, questions of this type ('at least') can be solved in two different ways.

One, by listing all the possibilities, which you've done so in the comments. Since the number of types of lettuce and nuts is given, we only need to decide how many ways we can choose the proteins. There are $\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{3}=4$ ways to do so.

Next, is by counting the complement. There is $1$ way to choose $0$ proteins and $3$ ways to choose $1$ proteins. There are $2^3$ different ways to choose proteins from $3$ types of proteins, and thus the required amount is $2^3-1-3=4$ ways.

In this case, the former is easier to calculate but the latter usually comes in useful too.

Either way, you will get $2*1*4=8$ ways.

Comment: I think you mean 2 * 1 * 4 = 8. Because for nuts: out of 4, all 4 needs to be selected so only 1 way to do it. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Apologies for the error.